# Average of independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of independent random variables. For each $n$, $\mathbb{P}(X_n=-n^2)=1/n^2$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=n^2/(n^2-1))=1-1/n^2$. I need to show that $(X_1+\dots+X_n)/n\rightarrow 1$ almost surely.

Can anyone point out how to prove this? Are there any theorems about sums of independent random variables that can be applied here?

Comment: What is $X$ and how are $X_1,X_2,\ldots,$ are distributed?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma